# PHP imagick or GD merge image from an array

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I was looking in google but I can't find any solution.

I need merge multiple png file via php. Everything works when I declarate image path like this:

```
    <?php
    $img1 = new Imagick('face.png');
    $img2 = new Imagick('glasses-1.png');
    $img1->compositeImage( $img2, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0 );
    $img1->setImageBackgroundColor('transparent');
    $img_wynik = $img1->flattenImages();
    $img_wynik->setImageFormat('png');
    $img_wynik->writeImage( 'avatar.png' );
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    echo $img_wynik;
    ?>
```

But I realy need to use images array, so i made test file and it doesn't work.

I thought I can use simple array like this

```
$srcImagesPath = array('glasses-1.png', 'mouth-1.png') //for example
```

and later change my testing code to this

```
$img2 = new Imagick ($srcImagesPath)
```

but it's always give me merged face.png and last image from array.

Any idea how to build it?

Comment: Just loop over the array to create new images, using for example the first as your base image.

Comment: foreach works! THANKS

Answer (score 0):

`$srcImagesPath` is an array, so you'll need to specify an element of it instead of passing the array itself. I guess you want:

```
$img2 = new Imagick ($srcImagesPath[0])
```

or

```
$img2 = new Imagick ($srcImagesPath[1])
```

Comment: no, i need merge all of images. This images will be selected by user so i can't declarate how much they will. I will parse this information from jQuery. I hope you understand my pure engish.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the GD library installed (assuming you have):

```
$image1 = imagefrompng('glasses-1.png');
$image2 = imagefrompng('mouth-1.png');
```

Once this is done you can create a frame in a new image using:

```
imagecopymerge()
```

I'll let you sort the destination, sources and coordinates... call it a challenge ;)

From there all you have to do is output the composited image to a file using imagepng:

```
imagepng($compositedImage, $path_to_filesystem_destination);
```

Using the command directly will output the image to the browser, the second parameter saves the image to a file.

Comment: this not what i need.